# Unsubscribing to rxjs observable using takeUntil and combineLatest not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am using the [accepted pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription?rq=1) for unsubscribing my Subscriptions:

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```

However, I am having issues with the following rxjs code using `takeUntil` and `combineLatest`:

```
this.observableA$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
    combineLatest(
        this.observableB$,
        this.observableC$
    )
).subscribe(([A, B, C]) => {
    // do some work   
})
```

This subscription seems to be persisting, as I can see the code firing multiple times after the component is destroyed and re-initialized. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inner observableB and observableC aren't unsubscribed. Try rearranging your operators:

```
combineLatest(
    this.observableB$,
    this.observableC$
),
takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
```

Comment: Yep. The last returned observable is subscribed to first, so the `takeUntil` should be as late as possible in the `pipe` to be as early as possible in the `subscribe` chain. +1.

Comment: Just tested swapping the operators and it works as expected! Thanks!